# Client-server communication on same machine via file or socket

Tags: security, sockets, web, client-server, ocx

I have a client-server relationship between two apps: a web application and an OCX. What I want to do is communicate the client part of the web application, running on the local PC, with the OCX, also installed in the same PC. The server app (the OCX) is not mine (I can't change its source code) and offers 2 ways of communicating with client apps: through an intermediate file or through a socket. There are lot of restrictions in the PCs where the apps have to be executed (the users, for example, are not administrators of their own PCs) so it's even more difficult than it seems. My doubt is which technology would be better to handle this communication from the cliente app (JavaScript, Java Applets, another OCX, etc.) and which option could be handled easier (file or sockets) by this technologies. And also which would be the security and permissions settings that should be taken into account to make it all work properly. You must know that, in case of using an intermediate file, I must be able to write in specific positions of that file from the web app (I'm not sure if Javascript's FileSystemObject can do this, for example). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Sockets is realy easy. I only don't know the security options of sockets. May be you can take a look here: [Oracle Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)